# Automatic vectorization GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization

I'm trying to get GCC 4.7 to automatically vectorize some parts of my code to provide a speed increase, however, it seems difficult to do so.

Here some code that I would like to vectorize:

```
void VideoLine::WriteOut(unsigned short * __restrict__  start_of_line, const int  number_of_sub_pixels_to_write)
{
  unsigned short * __restrict__ write_pointer = (unsigned short *)__builtin_assume_aligned (start_of_line, 16);
  unsigned short * __restrict__ line = (unsigned short *)__builtin_assume_aligned (_line, 16);
  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_sub_pixels_to_write; i++)
  {
    write_pointer[i] = line[i];
  }
}
```

I am using the following GCC switches:

```
-std=c++0x \
-o3 \
-msse \
-msse2 \
-msse3 \
-msse4.1 \
-msse4.2 \
-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=5\
-funsafe-loop-optimizations\
-march=corei7-avx \
-mavx \
-fdump-tree-vect-details \
-fdump-tree-optimized \
```

I'm aware that some override others.

I do not get any output from the vectorizer at all, however, when looking at the .optomized file, I can see it has not used vectorization. Can anyone point me in the right way to get this to vectorize?

**Edit:** Turned out the issue was using -o3 rather than -O3.

Comment: This is why I never rely on automatic vectorization. If it really matters, I do it manually.

Comment: you are just copying data. why would it vectorize?

Comment: Im just copying in this function but I have others that require more work. I assume it will be easier to get it to work on this first.

Comment: If you really care, vectorize it manually. Otherwise, use `std::copy`, and let the compiler decide how to optimize it.

Comment: Is the "-o3" really a small "o"? It should be a capital.

Comment: Cheers janneb - worked straight away!

Answer (score 0):

try to guarantee, that `number_of_sub_pixels_to_write` is a multiple of 4 by masking it like the way it is done here:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s04s03.html

Comment: does `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=5` include `-ftree-vectorize`?

Comment: @oc1d: In GCC 4.7 -ftree-vectorize is included in -O3

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is free to do what it pleases. Therefore, if you really want to use SIMD functionality (and not rely on the compiler), you should use the functions (see the [manual](http://cache-www.intel.com/cd/00/00/34/76/347603_347603.pdf)).